# Mapping resources with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I first setup Spring MVC to handle all urls.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And the dispatcher servlet mapped resources.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/VAADIN/resource/" />
```

This worked fine, but now I want to change Spring so that it only handle's '/search/' URLs.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/search/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This works but my resources no longer work. I think it's because it's looking for the resources in /search/resources rather than /resources. But I'm not sure.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your static resources visible , configure the static resources in your `web.xml`.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/VAADIN/resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

<sub>If `VAADIN` is the project name , need not specify it here</sub>

Comment: The project name is safesite. Full url of resources is "localhost/safesite/VAADIN/resource/"

I added that to my web.xml but now my other URLs for a different Dispatcher Servlet don't work.

Comment: The project name is safesite. Full url of resources is "localhost/safesite/VAADIN/resource/"

I added that to my web.xml with "default" changed to HelloWeb. Now going to the URL /safesite/resources/images/map.jpg works. Thanks!